# How these two lines of pointer execute?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct P{
  P *Pptr;
  int i;
};

int main(){
  P p1 = {NULL, 1};
  P p2 = {&p1, 2};
  P p3 = {&p2, 3};

cout << p3.Pptr->Pptr->i << endl;
 cout << p3.Pptr->i << endl;


}
```

How the lines cout << p3.Pptr->Pptr->i << endl;
 cout << p3.Pptr->i << endl;
executing in the program?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. What is it that you don't understand? If you can be more specific you'll get more useful help.

Comment: No I just want to learn the flow of pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After these statements

```
P p1 = {NULL, 1};
P p2 = {&p1, 2};
P p3 = {&p2, 3};
```

you have a chain (due to the data member Pptr)

```
p3 -> p2 -> p1 -> NULL
```

So this expression `p3.Pptr->Pptr->i` at first refers to `p2` (`p3.Pptr`) and then to `p1` `(p3.Pptr->Pptr)` and the value the data member `i` of the structure `p1` is outputted

This expression `p3.Pptr->i` refers to `p2` (`p3.Pptr`) and its data member `i` is outputted.

Answer (score 0):

```
p3.Pptr points to p2
p2.Pptr points to p1
p1.Pptr is NULL
```

> 1)cout << p3.Pptr->Pptr->i << endl;

```
    p3.Pptr->Pptr->i   is  1
```

> 2)cout << p3.Pptr->i << endl;

```
    p3.Pptr->i         is  2
```